# How to Evaluate $\int_1^4 (\frac{1}{2t}+i)^2 dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

**Question:**

> $$\int \limits _1^4\left (\frac{1}{2t}+i \right )^2\,dt.$$

How can I solve this? I believe its an indefinite integral and I can probably expand it by using $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ to get something like$$\int \frac{1}{4t^2}+\frac{2i}{2t}+i^2\,dt$$but I'm not even sure if that's right.

Comment: That $i$ it's a bad notation here. The $\int_{1}^{4}f(t)\,{\rm d}t$ is a *definite integral* and yes, you can use $(a+b)^{2}=a^{2}+2ab+b^{2}$. Then use $\int \frac{1}{t}\, {\rm d}t=\ln|t|+c$ and $\int t^{n}dt=\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$
\left(\frac1{2t}+i\right)^2=\frac1{4t^2}-1+\frac it,
$$
you have
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_1^4\left(\frac1{2t}+i\right)^2\,dt&=\int_1^4\frac1{4t^2}-1\,dt+\left(\int_1^4\frac1t\,dt\right)i\\
&=-\frac{45}{16}+i\log(4).
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{align*}\int \limits _1^4\left (\frac{1}{2t}+i\right )^2\,dt & =\int \limits _1^4\left (\frac{i}{t}+\frac{1}{4t^2}-1\right )\,dt \\
& =i\int \limits _1^4\frac{1}{t}\,dt+\frac{1}{4}\int \limits _1^4\frac{1}{t^2}\,dt-\int \limits _1^41\,dt \\
& =\left .i\ln |t|-t-\frac{1}{4t}\right |_1^4 \\
& =\frac{16i\ln 4-65}{16}+\frac{5}{4} \\
& =\frac{16i\ln 4-45}{16}.
\end{align*}

Comment: If $i^{2}=-1$ so what's the problem? There's not problem. However, I agree that to use $i$ is a bad notation here.

Comment: @EventHorizon no serious problem but as you said, horrible notation.

Comment: @EventHorizon edit: I automatically assumed that $i^2 = -1$ anyways to calculate it...